# Use Json Data Stored in App_data to show on google Map view using JavaScript and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

In my Code, I Created sample json data (Like Var Flensburg) in the view for Flensburg City. These Data Includes Name,Short-text and Images. So With This code I can show all this Places inside Flensburg with Name, Short-text and Images.I want to change my code which I mentioned in comment section in code.My Code is as follows-

**Modified Code**

```
 @model  PoiFinder.Models.City

 <div class="row wrapper border-bottom white-bg page-heading">

 <div class="col-lg-10">
    <h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Back</a>
        </li>

    </ol>
   </div>

   </div>

   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <style>
    #map_canvas img {
    max-width: none;
  }
 </style>
 <style>
.infoDiv {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    background-color: white;
  }
  </style>
 <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 600px;"></div>
 @section scripts {
 <section class="scripts">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetGeoData", "Home")',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (getGeoData) {
                Initialize(getGeoData);
            }
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            Initialize();
        });

        function Initialize() {

            google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
            var Flensburg = new google.maps.LatLng(54.78194444, 9.43666667);


            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 14,
                center: Flensburg,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.G_NORMAL_MAP
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(54.78194444, 9.43666667);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: 'Tate Gallery'
            });

            marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png')


            $.each(getGeoData, function (i, item) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    'position': new google.maps.LatLng(item.GeoCoordinates.Longitude, item.GeoCoordinates.Latitude),
                    'map': map,
                    'title': item.Name
                });


                marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png')


                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: "<div class='infoDiv'><h1>"+item.Name+"</h1><h5>" + item.Shorttext + "</h5>" + "<div><img src="+item.Images+"></div></div>"
                });


                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });

            })
        }


     </script>
   </section>
   }
```

Now What I want to do I want to make it Dynamic suppose in my App_data I stored many Json File of city with its interesting places and images. An Example is in Kiel.json file i stored data like this,

```
{
"poi": [
    {
        "Name": "Laboe Naval Memorial",
        "Shorttext": "The Laboe Naval Memorial is a memorial located in Laboe, near Kiel, in Schleswig-Holstein, Germany. Started in 1927 and completed in 1936, the monument .",
        "GeoCoordinates": {
            "Longitude": 10.23079681,
            "Latitude": 54.41218567
        },
        "Images": [

            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/15/Marine_-_Ehrenmal_Laboe.jpg/300px-Marine_-_Ehrenmal_Laboe.jpg"


        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "Zoological Museum of Kiel University",
        "Shorttext": "The Zoological Museum of Kiel University is a zoological museum in Kiel, Germany. It was founded by naturalist Karl Möbius, and architect Martin Gropiu.",
        "GeoCoordinates": {
            "Longitude": 10.14416695,
            "Latitude": 54.32805634
        },
        "Images": [
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Zoologisch-Voelkerkundl_Museum_Kiel_1.jpg/400px-Zoologisch-Voelkerkundl_Museum_Kiel_1.jpg"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "Kieler Förde",
        "Shorttext": "Kieler Förde is an approximately 17 km long inlet of the Baltic Sea on the eastern side of Schleswig-Holstein, Germany. Formed by glacial movement during the las.",
        "GeoCoordinates": {
            "Longitude": 10.17305556,
            "Latitude": 54.36777778
        },
        "Images": [
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fd/Kiel_Luftaufnahme.JPG/400px-Kiel_Luftaufnahme.JPG"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "German submarine U-995",
        "Shorttext": "German submarine U-995 is a Type VIIC/41 U-boat of Nazi Germany's Kriegsmarine. She was .",
        "GeoCoordinates": {
            "Longitude": 10.22888889,
            "Latitude": 54.4125
        },
        "Images": [
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/U995_2004_1.jpg/400px-U995_2004_1.jpg"
        ]
    }
  .............. so on.
```

I want to get Name, Shorttext, Images from this Kiel.json file in my code. As I am very new in handling this situation I could not get logic how to proceed.

I created Json object in the model class like this-

```
 public class GeoCoordinates
{
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
}
public class Poi
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Shorttext { get; set; }
    public GeoCoordinates GeoCoordinates { get; set; }
    public List<string> Images { get; set; }
 }
public class RootObject
{
  public List<Poi> poi { get; set; }

 }
```

My Controller class to take the name is as follows-

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(City objCityModel)
    {
        string name = objCityModel.Name;
        return View();
    }
  public ActionResult GoogleMap(City objCityModel)
    {
        string name = objCityModel.Name;
        ViewBag.Title = name;
     return View();

    }

  public JsonResult GetGeoData(City objCityModel)
   {
    string name = objCityModel.Name;
    ViewBag.Title = name;
    string appDataPath = Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/POI_Json/");
    string file = Path.Combine(appDataPath, "Kiel.json");

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(file))
    {
        using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            string jsonData = stream.ReadToEnd();
            var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData, typeof(RootObject));
            return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
    return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I create a textbox and button in index view to go according to the city name. I just give this code for understanding-

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("GoogleMap", "Home"))
   {
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
        <label for="somevalue">City Name</label>

        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button id="mapViewBtn" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Map View</button>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Check out this guide http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/082510-1.aspx

Comment: @mwwallace8 This link is for SQL. But in my case I stored the ,json file in APP_data. It is different from my code.

Answer (score 0):

Create an action which will return your json Data. 
call it from ajax .

```
public JsonResult GetgeoData()
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Kiel.json")))
            {
                var getData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(sr.ReadToEnd());
                return Json(getData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Call this action before calling `Initialize();` add a parameter to your Initialize function.

like

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetgeoData", "yourcontrollername")',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (getGeoData) {
            Initialize(getGeoData.poi);
        }
    });
```

and inside your `Initialize` function.
run the each loop

```
 $.each(getGeoData, function (i, item) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    'position': new google.maps.LatLng(item.GeoCoordinates.Longitude, item.GeoCoordinates.Latitude),
                    'map': map,
                    'title': item.Name
                });
```

Comment: Could you please explain what can I do in the controller class. I mean how to add data ´here. Do I need any deserialization of json data for this. I am very new in ASP.NET. I modified my code. Could you please have a look

Comment: @harry.luson: See my updated answer. It's tested and working.